# Tengo un problema o Error con JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con JSON y no se como corregir

Llamo a la función de esta manera

```
function mostrar(idgrado){ 
  $.post("../ajax/grados.php?op=mostrar",{idgrado:idgrado}, fun‌​ction(data,status){ 
     data= JSON.parse(data); 
     mostrarfomr(true); 
     $("#nombregrado").val(data.nombregrado); 
     $("#idgrado").val(data.idgrado); 
   }) 
}
```

Los datos viene desde una consulta sql

adjunto una imágen por favor ayúdenme[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pon tus codigos

Comment: function mostrar(idgrado){

$.post("../ajax/grados.php?op=mostrar",{idgrado:idgrado},function(data,status){

data= JSON.parse(data);
mostrarfomr(true);
$("#nombregrado").val(data.nombregrado);
$("#idgrado").val(data.idgrado);
})


}

Los datos viene desde una consulta sql

Comment: Bienvenido ..., te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable ser especifico, recuerda que las actualizaciones de información las debes realizar en tu pregunta!, saludos!

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: Agrega tu código en la pregunta pero no imagenes del código, usa la opción ["editar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/117082/edit), saludos.

Comment: Revisa en la consola del browser qué obtienes como respuesta a tu petición POST. Mi mejor supuesto es que estás obteniendo un mensaje de error en HTML (ya sea error 404 o 50x), el cual viene formateado como HTML. Por lo anterior, comienza con `<` y eso no es una cadena JSON válida. Otra opción es que no sea realmente un error, pero sí estés devolviendo HTML desde un backend mientras que tu llamada espera una respuesta en JSON

Answer (score 0):

estas recibiendo dos parametros function (a,b)  success y solo estas convirtiendo uno ¿por que tienes dos parametros y solo estas mandando un parametro?
asi debe de quedar con un parametro

```
echo json_encode($respuesta);


function (data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data)
```

}

igual revisa en el network si trae informacion tu arreglo

Comment: Estoy revisado gracias. En un momento lo comento

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Gracias por su lo logre areglar gracias

Comment: puedes decirnos cual fue la solucion por favor